# Colocar web application online (publicar) feito no visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Desenvolvi um website em *asp.net C#* no *Visual Studio 2013* para uma empresa. Essa empresa quer substituir o seu site atual pelo que eu desenvolvi. Esse site encontra-se no servidor de uma empresa telefônica. Como é que eu faço para substituir os ficheiros do site antigo pelos meus, ou seja, o que tenho de fazer para colocar o meu site a funcionar?

Comment: Depende muito da estrutura do ambiente onde vai publicar, restrições de segurança, como você configurou as strings de conexões com os bancos e serviços externos. Mas basicamente você utiliza o Publish do visual studio, faz o upload para o servidor... Ou pelo web deploy conectando diretamente no IIS... São muitas alternativas.

Comment: Já tentei utilizar o publish mas não encontro as informações (username e pass) no servidor onde quero colocar o site..

Comment: a empresa para a qual eu fiz o Website forneceu-me uma passe e um nome de utilizador..

Comment: ftp, terminal cliente ou para o web deploy? Seja mais claro em relação às informações que dá,  senão não tem como ajudar... Já entrou em contato com eles e perguntou?

Comment: A única coisa que me disseram foi "através do gestor de ficheiros, fiz o upload do website (copy-paste)"..

Comment: E qual é o erro???

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78476/discussion-between-m-carreira-and-leandro-angelo).

Comment: O site antigo está em asp.net mvc c#?

Comment: O servidor é microsoft?

Comment: A menos que seja asp.net-core esse site só corre em windows